# GLSL reciprocal trigonometric functions

Tags: glsl

I want to express a formula with sec(x) in it in my GLSL shader. I assume, that GLSL does not have such reciprocal trigonometric functions and there seems to be no extension providing them. No sec(x), no csc(x), no cot(x). We are forced to do 1/cos(x), 1/sin(x) and cos(x)/sin(x) respectively.

Am I understanding the situation correctly? Should I rephrase my formulas without reciprocal trigonometric functions to avoid doing a costly 1/x division? Am I overthinking it and doing placebo optimizations?